# Continuously subtract value from column using another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

| Category | Number | Constant |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | 141.2 | 271.01 |
| One | 57.4 | 271.01 |
| One | 51.3 | 271.01 |
| Two | 24.69 | 27.29 |
| Two | 12.72 | 27.29 |
| Two | 10.37 | 27.29 |

What I want is something that can iterate through each row and calculate a new value of the constant given the previous value of the constant. The resulting dataframe should look something like this:

| Category | Number | Constant |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | 141.2 | 129.99 |
| One | 57.4 | 72.59 |
| One | 51.3 | 21.29 |
| Two | 24.69 | 2.6 |
| Two | 12.72 | -10.12 |
| Two | 10.37 | -20.49 |

Update: The calculation is Number-constant for the first calculation and then for the rest would be constant[n-1] - number[n]

Is there a way to do this without using a for loop?

Comment: you can use pandas map function and do the operation without using a for loop

Comment: What is the calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) to compute the cumulative sum and subtract this from "Constant":

```
df['Constant'] -= df.groupby('Category')['Number'].cumsum()
```

Alternatively, if you don't want an in place operation

```
df['New_Col'] = df['Constant'].sub(df.groupby('Category')['Number'].cumsum())
```

Output:

```
  Category  Number  Constant
0      One  141.20    129.81
1      One   57.40     72.41
2      One   51.30     21.11
3      Two   24.69      2.60
4      Two   12.72    -10.12
5      Two   10.37    -20.49
```